# Empty select version Apache Ambari 2.7.6

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I installed & built Apache Ambari 2.7.6 from:
[Installation Guide for Ambari 2.7.6](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.6) .In launch install wizard step 1, Select Version is empty. How can i pass this step without using HDP/HDF and use own Apache?

Thanks

[Installer step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NArkY.png)

Comment: I believe a stack is needed, such as Apache BigTop. You cannot really "add Ambari" to an existing Hadoop system

Answer (score 1):

To use open source with Ambari you'd need to build ambari with this patch:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-25366
- You can also use the Mpack that is provided by BigTop in this
  pull: https://github.com/apache/bigtop/pull/669

It installs a management pack that could then be used to to install [BigTop](https://bigtop.apache.org/) which is an opensource version of hadoop that packages versions of the Hadoop Zoo.

1. Build Ambari (with that patch) in ticket above, or download the management pack from BigTop
2. Install [the Bigtop management pack](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Management+Packs)
3. Then the 'bigTop' installed version will become available in the wizard.

Comment: to download the management pack from BigTop i follow these steps:                             - git clone https://github.com/guyuqi/bigtop-mpack
- cd bgtp bgtp-ambari-mpack
- mvn clean package -DskipTests build bgtp-ambari-mpack-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT-bgtp-ambari-mpack.tar.gz
and it return this error :                                                                                         [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/hadoop/bigtop-mpack). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]